# Async interactions between A-Frame components

Tags: javascript, virtual-reality, aframe

I'm currently trying to spawn an object in case there's an intersection between a laser object and a collidable object. I'm using a raycaster to detect the collision.

To spawn the object I want to do it only in the case there's a collision and also the user has pressed the trigger button.

I was thinking on creating a global variable `pressed` when the `triggerdown` event listener was pressed and in the `raycaster-intersection` event listener spawn an object only if this variable was set to true.

```
const pressed = false

AFRAME.registerComponent('laser', {
  init: function () {
    const laser = this.el.sceneEl.querySelector('#laser');
    laser.addEventListener('raycaster-intersection', function(event) {
      console.log('raycaster-intersection', event.detail.intersections[0].point)
      if (pressed) {
        console.log('spawn')
      }
    });
  }
})

AFRAME.registerComponent('spawner', {
  init: function () {
    const blockHand = this.el.sceneEl.querySelector('#blockHand');
    blockHand.addEventListener('triggerdown', function(event) {
      pressed = true
    });
    blockHand.addEventListener('triggerup', function(event) {
      pressed = false
    });
  }
})
```

I don't like to use global variables but I don't know how could I tackle this problem without them in this case.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some solutions:

1. Do `this.el.addState('pressed')` and `this.el.removeState('pressed')` to update the state, and use `this.el.is('pressed')` to check it.
2. Combine the components together and store it as `this.pressed`.
3. A-Frame master build, soon 0.6.0, has a laser-controls component you can use https://aframe.io/docs/master/components/laser-controls.html so all you have to do is listen for `click` rather than having to listen for both raycaster intersection and trigger down. And you get all controller support for free.